# how to place php variable in wordpress tincymce editor

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, tinymce

I need to place php variable in visual tinymce editor(wordpress) using specific tag.

For example, if wordpress template file is like below

```
<?php
 $test = 'test'
?>
```

then user can use the value in tincymce visual editor like below

```
Hi. [php]echo $test;[/php]
```

I could not find any tinymce nor wordpress plugin that allows the feature.

Does anyone know how to achieve the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use the [string replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) method on the TinyMCE's content.

In the example below, the string `%%string%%` will be replaced with `$var` in `$content`

```
$content = str_replace( '%%string%%', $var, $content );
```

**Note:** `%%string%%` can be whatever you want, just make up something unique.